# installing .NET core on Ubuntu 15.10 failed

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I tried to install .NET core on Ubuntu 15.10. I followed this link: 
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu

and the moment I got to the second stage and I had to type:
sudo apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003131

I got the following error message:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003131 : Depends:
>   dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.0.1 but it is not going
>   to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

Do you have any idea what to do?

Comment: As you can see from the instructions for the first step, there are only repos for Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 but not 15.10, so the second step will fail for you. Consider upgrading to 16.04 since 15.10 has already gone EOL.

Comment: Can I upgrade without formatting my disk?

Comment: Nope, you don't need to format. But I can't guarantee things wouldn't break because of the upgrade. Best practice is to do a backup before upgrading.

Comment: I upgraded to version 16, and now .net core is installed successfully.